# Saving a spreadsheet to disk using java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to store the uploaded spreadsheet to the disk. I am using the below code to do the same and receiving the file is corrupted error from the excel.

```
    byte[] bytes = null;
    File uploadedFile = new File("D://xlsxTest//BNG Issue.xlsx"); 
    File file = new File("D://xlsxTest//sample1.xlsx");

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try{
    if(!file.exists()){
       file.createNewFile();
   }
   outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (uploadedFile != null) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);;

        int c = 0;
        while (c != -1) {
            c = inputStream.read();
            byteArrayOutputStream.write((char) c);

        }
        bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    }

    outStream.write(bytes);
           }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
        outStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried using a file of 83KB size and the resultant file is 82.5KB.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you saving it properly and can't read the text inside ?

Comment: Try to add `outStream.flush()` before closing it .

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You code simply adds an additional byte (-1) at the end of the file because the test for end of file occurs **after** the write. But it should never result in a shorter copy. Can you confirm that with above code "D://xlsxTest//sample1.xlsx" is shorter that "D://xlsxTest//BNG Issue.xlsx"?

Comment: Yes it is shorter.

Comment: Could you share the source xlsx file?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Apace POI, Convert .xls or .xlsx file to byte array using OPCPackage and XSSFWorkbook with below code.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File(fullFileName));
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    wb.write(baos);
    byte[] fileContent = baos.toByteArray();
```

Apache POI takes care to extract all information of the excel file while converting to byte array.

Comment: The issue is solved if I write the code above way. But I may have a possibility of getting a very huge file and  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg); is resulting into outofmemory issues. So wanted to avoid the same.

Comment: Is there a formula cells in the excel file ?? If there is any cyclic reference or if there is invalid formulas, You would get StackOverflow error.

Comment: I am not getting a StackOverflow error. The file is getting saved but on opening Excel say the file is corrupted.